# Codeigniter pagination is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am using codeigniter pagination. But I'm facing a problem while using codeingiter pagination. Here is the issue which I am facing.

Ex: If there are more than 10 records for a page and here I am displaying 5 records per page. If I click on the second page it is displaying the data correctly but if I need to go back for the first page it is not working. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
class Testimonial extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct();
        //here we will autoload the pagination library
        $this->load->model('testimonial_model');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }
public function index()
{

    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url('testimonial/index');
    $config['total_rows'] =   $this->testimonial_model->record_count();//here we will count all the data from the table
    $config['per_page'] = 2;//number of data to be shown on single page
    $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["records2"] = $this->testimonial_model->get_all_testimonials($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();//create the link for pagination
    $data['mainpage'] = "testimonial";
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}   
}
```

Model:

```
class Testimonial_model extends CI_Model
{    
function get_all_testimonials($limit, $start)
{
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('T.*');
    $this->db->from('testimonials AS T');
    $this->db->where(array('T.status'=>1));
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $q->result();
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function record_count()
{
    return $this->db->count_all("testimonials");
}
}
```

Comment: Please go with this URL : http://www.technicalkeeda.com/php-codeigniter/pagination-using-php-codeigniter

Comment: @HardikPaghdar tried this one not able to fetch the data getting only pagination

Comment: Info is missing to fully understand, ...but: How many items per page should be displayed? ...from your controller code it looks like you show $config['per_page'] item per page. Always 2 in your code! You should do something like: 
$config['per_page'] = ($this->uri->segment(N)) ? $this->uri->segment(N) : 2;  // where N is the uri segment where you indicate items-per-page to be shown.

Comment: @marc i need to display 5 per page if i click on the next page it is working for all but if i need to go for page 1 it is not working

Answer (score 0):

use this answer please read the code once to understand it

```
public function index()
{

    $config = array();

    //$config["base_url"] = base_url('testimonial/index');

        $get_vars = $this->input->get();
        if(is_array($get_vars))
        $config['suffix'] = '?'.http_build_query($get_vars,'', "&");
        //$config['prefix'] = '?'.http_build_query($get_vars,'', "&");
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().$this->router->class.'/index';
        $config['first_url'] = $config['base_url'] . (isset($config['suffix'])?$config['suffix']:'');

    $config['total_rows'] =   $this->testimonial_model->record_count();//here we will count all the data from the table
    $config['per_page'] = 2;//number of data to be shown on single page


    //this line should be according to url to fetch actual value
    $config["uri_segment"] = ($this->uri->segment('2')?$this->uri->segment('2'):0); // 2 or 3 based on ur url


    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = $config["uri_segment"];
    $data["records2"] = $this->testimonial_model->get_all_testimonials($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();//create the link for pagination
    $data['mainpage'] = "testimonial";
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

Comment: what is page? can u explain me? it should be $page = $config["uri_segment"];

Comment: getting page not found

Comment: what is the url of page not found? please share it.

Comment: It is working for page 2 again if i need to click on page 1 it is in disable

Comment: $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0; u changed this with $page= $config["uri_segment"] ; and use proper number in $this->uri->segment('2'); 2 or 3 as ur need

Comment: $page= $config["uri_segment"] ;  $this->uri->segment('2') : 0;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129795/discussion-between-user7047368-and-kool-mind).